# How can I capture two time periods for a single status?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 3 columns like below:

| ID | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | T | 2022-09-27 |
| 001 | T | 2022-09-26 |
| 001 | T | 2022-09-25 |
| 001 | T | 2022-09-24 |
| 001 | T | 2022-09-23 |
| 001 | T | 2022-09-22 |
| 001 | T | 2022-09-21 |
| 001 | R | 2022-09-20 |
| 001 | R | 2022-09-19 |
| 001 | R | 2022-09-18 |
| 001 | R | 2022-09-17 |
| 001 | R | 2022-09-16 |
| 001 | T | 2022-09-15 |
| 001 | T | 2022-09-14 |
| 001 | T | 2022-09-13 |
| 001 | T | 2022-09-12 |
| 001 | T | 2022-09-11 |
| 001 | T | 2022-09-10 |
| 001 | T | 2022-09-09 |
| 001 | T | 2022-09-08 |
| 001 | T | 2022-09-07 |
| 001 | T | 2022-09-06 |

How can I generate an output like this in Snowflake?

| ID | Status | Start_date | End_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | T | 2022-09-21 | 2022-09-27 |
| 001 | T | 2022-09-06 | 2022-09-15 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is "gaps and islands" class problem. The easiest way is to use [MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/match_recognize.html) clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
   PARTITION BY ID
   ORDER BY Date
   MEASURES
        CLASSIFIER() AS Status
       ,MIN(Date) AS Start_date
       ,MAX(Date) AS End_date
   PATTERN (T+)
   DEFINE T AS Status = 'T'
) AS mr;
```

Output:

[image]